# Hypothesis test for the difference in Logistic regression probabilities (R glm)

Tags: regression, logistic, standard-error, pooling

```
dummy_data <- data.frame(
     x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
     x2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
     y = round(runif(100, 0, 1), 0)
)

dummy_glm <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2,
                 data = dummy_data,
                 family = binomial(link = 'logit')
                 )
```

I get a standard error of the probability output for one observation:

```
X <- as.matrix(cbind(rep(1, times = 100), dummy_data[, c('x1', 'x2')]), ncol = 3)

### FOR LOGISTIC RGRESSION

pi <- dummy_glm$fitted.values

w <- pi * (1 - pi)

v <- diag(w, length(w), length(w))

XtX_inv <- solve(t(X) %*% v %*% X)

# standard error for linear combination (first observation in data frame)

C <- c(1, dummy_data[1, 'x1'], dummy_data[1, 'x2'])

std_err_manually <- as.numeric(sqrt(t(C) %*% XtX_inv %*% C))
```

So, I am able to get probability p1, and standard error SE1 respective to a feature vector X1 of observation A (a specific person doing something at a specific moment in time). Other observations (Xi) used to fit the logistic model are randomly sampled and independent.

Then, suppose I have a new feature vector X2 with respect to observation A, which has a physical meaning of how the person behaved at another moment of time, which does not overlap with the first time period. I assume here that X1 and X2 are not necessarily dependent, so they can be arbitrarily different.

I run the new vector of features through my trained model and get probability p2 and standard error of prediction SE2.

**I wanto to test if p1 is significatly different from p2. Z = (p1 - p2) / pooled_se.**

**Question:** A confusion arises when 1) I decide how to get a pooled standard deviation, and 1.a) what are the degrees of freedom? Are these the number of observations used in model fitting, or are these equal to 1, since I run a hypothesis test for just one observation?

Comment: So, I do not have sample standard deviations to be able to figure out the pooled St.Dev (Cohen's or other forms). Instead I have sample-wise standard errors. My first thought is to use pooled standard error to be (SE1 + SE2) / 2, i.e., arithmetic mean.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, testing the difference in probabilities in a logistic regression is the same as testing whether some linear combination of the population coefficients differs from 0. You can do an asymptotic test using the estimated coefficients and the variance-covariance matrix, or you can implement it via fitting two models, one free and the other where the difference is constrained to be 0.

Comment: I do not test if a probability value differs from zero, but I rather test that two probability values returned for two different feature vectors but using the same model coefficients are different. **" is the same as testing whether some linear combination of the population coefficients differs from 0"** I understand this. But am I doing right in the presence of one set of coefficients, but different feature inputs to the fitted model, namely, **Z = (p1 - p2) / sqrt(SE1^2 + SE2^2)**?

Comment: "two different feature vectors but using the same model coefficients are different." -- yes, that's what I was discussing. In relation to your formula,  whuber already told you why the answer is no -- why do you need to be told twice? (in any case, I mentioned that you need to deal with the covariance above, so actually this is now three times -- and if someone else comments tomorrow, these mathematical facts still won't change; so it will still be no tomorrow.) ... if you had different sets of data things would be different then but that's not what you're asking about.

Comment: Why be so nnoyed? ) I just do not understand completely why I am facing correlated values (per whuber's suggestion). Suggesting a hard math explanation would be helpful, a textbook or webpage that goes into these details. These are 100 year-old concepts, I agree, but I just don't understand the idea. *And yes I do have two different sets of data, as I pointed in my original question.* I need, though, to test whether observation-wise pairs of returned probabilities (p1 and se1 for old data, and p2 and se2 for new data) are different in the presence of the same model's coefficients.

Comment: How can they be different sets of data if the values of the coefficients are the same?

Comment: Thank you. Could you review one more answer to my questions that I have just posted? I simulated probabilities for random input features and did not find the correlations, even though I use one set of coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an answer for equal variances and equal sample size:

```
xx <- rnorm(100, 0, 2) #Population SD = 2
yy <- rnorm(100, 0, 2) #Population SD = 2

# xx <- rnorm(100, 0, 1) #Population SD = 1
# yy <- rnorm(100, 0, 2) #Population SD = 2



SEp <- 2 * sqrt(1/100 + 1/100) # pooled SE with equal population variances

SEp <- sqrt(1^2/100 + 2^2/100) #for unknown variances, using sample SDs

# sample-wise standard errors

SEx <- 1/sqrt(100)
SEy <- 1/sqrt(100)


# given SEs only

SEp_alt <- sqrt(SEx^2 + SEy^2)

print(paste0('full calculation = ', SEp, '; ', 'SE only calculation = ', SEp_alt))
```

So the answer would be; pooled SE equals

```
sqrt(SEx^2 + SEy^2)
```

which matches the pooled SE result with both known and unknown population standard deviation, and equal sample sizes.

Comment: This is inapplicable to your question because the two predictions are strongly correlated.  It will usually be very wrong, not just a little bit off.

Comment: Hello. Why are the predictions correlated? Does one model make them be correlated?

Comment: I refer to my problem as to a paired two-sample test. What if I fit a new model using the new dataset? I will get another vector of coefficients, which means a different model. However, I double if I will be able to say that I still make a pair-wise comparison of the sample means. Seems hard to me.

Comment: Your comment, your answer, and your question don't seem to have much to do with one another.  Could you edit your question to clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected my initial question to get a better intuition behind the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the correlations between probabilities returned by logistic regression model. I mean Pearson correlations for two random variables of probabilities. I build 5 000 sets of random feature vectors, assuming that each observation in any set is pairwise connected to the observation in any other set (same entities are under testing). I assume that the model quality is good, and there is a linear separability of classes corrupted my controlled level of Guassian noise.

```
rm(list = ls()); gc()

library(data.table)

#dummy_data <- read.csv('dummy_data.csv')

dummy_data <- data.table(
     x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
     x2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
)
dummy_data[, y := ifelse(x1 + x2 + rnorm(1, 0, 0.5) >= 0, 1, 0)]


dummy_glm <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 -1,
                 data = dummy_data,
                 family = binomial(link = 'logit')
                 )

summary(dummy_glm)

# run simulation
iterations <- 5000
fit_list <- list()

for (i in 1:iterations){

     fit_list[[i]] <- predict(
          object = dummy_glm,
          newdata = dummy_data,
          se.fit = T,
          type = 'response'
     )$fit

     # make new independent inputs vars

     dummy_data <- data.table(
          x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
          x2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
     )
     dummy_data[, y := ifelse(x1 + x2 + rnorm(1, 0, 0.5) >= 0, 1, 0)]

}

fit_probabilities <- t(do.call(rbind, fit_list))

fit_prob_corr_matrix <- cor(fit_probabilities)

x <- fit_prob_corr_matrix[lower.tri(fit_prob_corr_matrix, diag = FALSE)]

hist(x, breaks = 'fd', main = paste0('density over Pearson Corr Coef after ', iterations, ' iterations'))
```

I did not find significant correlations.

[image]

So I am asking again why you say the p values stemming from one model with different, independent features as an input would be correlated. Are there specific assumptions that should be met to satisfy this?